# Function returning a class containing a function returning a class

Tags: vba, oop, excel

I'm working on an object-oriented Excel add-in to retrieve information from our ERP system's database. Here is an example of a function call:

`itemDescription = Macola.Item("12345").Description`

Macola is an instance of a class which takes care of database access. Item() is a function of the Macola class which returns an instance of an ItemMaster class. Description() is a function of the ItemMaster class. This is all working correctly.

Items can be be stored in more than one location, so my next step is to do this:

`quantityOnHand = Macola.Item("12345").Location("A1").QuantityOnHand`

Location() is a function of the ItemMaster class which returns an instance of the ItemLocation class (well, in theory anyway). QuantityOnHand() is a function of the ItemLocation class. But for some reason, the ItemLocation class is not even being intialized.

```
Public Function Location(inventoryLocation As String) As ItemLocation
    Set Location = New ItemLocation
    Location.Item = item_no
    Location.Code = inventoryLocation
End Function
```

In the above sample, the variable item_no is a member variable of the ItemMaster class.

Oddly enough, I can successfully instantiate the ItemLocation class outside of the ItemMaster class in a non-class module.

```
Dim test As New ItemLocation
test.Item = "12345"
test.Code = "A1"
quantityOnHand = test.QuantityOnHand
```

Is there some way to make this work the way I want? I'm trying to keep the API as simple as possible. So that it only takes one line of code to retrieve a value.

Comment: I know this is example code meant to exhibit a problem, so you might already be aware of it, but those who aren't should Google the "Law of Demeter"...

Comment: How do you know that ".. for some reason, the ItemLocation class is not even being intialized." ??

Comment: @jtolle - I haven't obscured anything here. I googled "Law of Demeter" but not sure what you consider problematic about my code?

@RBarryYoung - I've got some code in the Class_Intialize of the ItemLocation class to print a debug message. No message = no init.

Comment: Scott, no problem. It's just an OO design guideline about reducing coupling between classes. It's not directly relevant to this problem, but often chains of method invocations indicate there is a better design waiting to emerge. See this classic article (which doesn't actually mention "Demeter" at all): http://media.pragprog.com/articles/may_04)_oo1.pdf. As far as your problem, your syntax looks fine; I can't figure out what the problem is. Could you post more of your actual code? Any more attention will from me will have to wait until tomorrow, as I have an appointment with a margarita...

Comment: @Scott In your `Location` function, you have a line that says `Location.Item = item_no`.  Where is `item_no` coming from? You're treating it like it's a variable, but from the code you provided, I don't see `item_no` declared anywhere.  Perhaps that's not a big deal, but maybe that's the reason your function isn't working?

Comment: If you're not seeing an instance of 'ItemLocation' get created at all, does that mean you're also not seeing a call to your 'Location' method of class 'ItemMaster'?

Comment: @Ben - it's a member variable of the class in which the function is contained. @jtolle - correct, the Location method appears to be not firing either.

Comment: Have you tried splitting up your single line to see just where things are failing? That is, have 'Set master = Macola.Item("12345")', 'Set loc = master.Location()', etc.? I think we're all assuming that you're getting your ItemMaster instance just fine, that you're not suppressing an error with 'On Error Resume Next', and so on...

Comment: Yes, I've been trying a split up version too. It was not performing any differently. However, since the changes made this morning based on dkusleika's suggestion, everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your function refers to Location, it creates a New ItemLocation (because it recalls the function, recursive like), or so it seems.  Maybe you need to isolate the ItemMaster inside the function, like this

```
Public Property Get Location(inventoryLocation As String) As ItemLocation

    Dim clsReturn As ItemLocation

    Set clsReturn = New ItemLocation

    clsReturn.Item = "item_no"
    clsReturn.Code = inventoryLocation

    Set Location = clsReturn

End Property
```

I'm not sure why you use a function instead of a property, but if you have a good reason, I'm sure you can adapt this.  I also couldn't figure out where item_no came from, so I made it a string.

Comment: I think your solution is almost exactly like mine.  I recognized the same problem, but apparently it didn't help :-/

Comment: Right Ben.  I swear I read all the other answers before I posted, but clearly I didn't.
Correct jtolle.

Comment: This is a little different than what Ben suggested. I tried it out but either the code is never running or the ItemMaster class is somehow terminating before it gets a chance to run.

Comment: I just reloaded the file and now this is working. The only changes I made this morning were based on dkusleika's suggestion, so I guess this is the solution. Items can exist in multiple locations, but I can deal with that by creating a collection.

Comment: @dkus Perhaps the difference lies in that yours is a property and mine is a function? Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You might try separating out the declaration and instantiation of objects in your VBA code.  I would also create an object variable local to the function and return it at the end.  Try this:

```
Public Function Location(inventoryLocation As String) As ItemLocation
    Dim il As ItemLocation        'Declare the local object '
    Set il = New ItemLocation     'Instantiate the object on a separate line '
    il.Item = item_no
    il.Code = inventoryLocation
    Set Location = il             'Return the local object at the end '
End Function
```

I'm not sure if this is what caused the problem, but I remember reading that VB6/VBA has a problem with declaring and instantiating an object on the same line of code.  I always separate out my `Dim` from my `Set` in VBA into two lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It made no difference, however.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to reproduce this, but let me report what I did and maybe that will help you find your problem.

Here is the code for Class1:

```
Public Function f() As Class2
    Set f = New Class2
    f.p = 42
End Function
```

and here is the code for Class2:

```
Private p_

Public Property Let p(value)
    p_ = value
End Property

Public Property Get p()
    p = p_
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Class 2 init"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Class 2 term"
End Sub
```

If I go to the immediate window and enter:

```
set c1=new Class1
```

and then

```
?c1.f().p
```

I get back:

```
Class 2 init
 42 
Class 2 term
```

So an instance of Class2 gets created, it's property 'p' gets written and read, but then VBA kills it after that line executes because no variable has a reference to that instance.

Like I said, this doesn't match up with your problem as described. I am probably missing some point in the details, but I hope this helps.

EDIT:

To clarify, I mean for my simpler example of calling 'c1.f().p' to correspond to your

```
quantityOnHand = Macola.Item("12345").Location("A1").QuantityOnHand
```

but my simpler example works just fine. So you now have three answers that amount to "need more info", but it's an interesting little puzzle.

If you're not seeing an instance of 'ItemLocation' get created at all, does that mean you're also not seeing a call to your 'Location' method of class 'ItemMaster'? So possibly the problem is upstream from the 'Location' code posted.